Quantlib: flat forward curve construction with spreads + jumps
I am trying to build a flat forward curve with some specificities. The input data for this curve is a mix of forward rates, zero spreads and jump specifications. See an example dataset below:
FORWARD RATES

21nov2024 - 28nov2024: 3%
28nov2024 - 21dec2024: 2.6%

I have used the ForwardCurve object to construct the curve based on the above data.
ZERO SPREADS

21nov2024 - 25nov2024: +10bps
21nov2024 - 20dec2024: +15bps

JUMPS

29nov2024 - 2dec2024: +100bps

I would like to add the above items in a flat forward fashion, ie the forward rates from the zero spreads should not be linearly interpolated between themselves but instantly rise to the next value on the end dates.
I have tried to investigate various tools in the package but am struggling to add the spreads and jumps on top of the base curve in an elegant way.
Please see minimal code example below. I specifically want to not have the significant jump in the 1d forward rate on 25nov2024 before the rate goes to the expected spread
import QuantLib as ql
import utils

def get_forward_curve_adjusted_dates_rates(start_date: ql.Date, base_curve_data: list, jump_spec: tuple) -> tuple:
    dates = [start_date]
    rates = [0]
    jump_start = jump_spec[0]
    jump_end = jump_spec[1]
    jump = jump_spec[2]
    for idx, row in enumerate(base_curve_data):
        last_value_date = dates[idx]
        value_date = row[0]
        forward_rate = row[1]
        if last_value_date < jump_end <= value_date:
            dates.append(jump_start)
            dates.append(jump_end)
            rates.append(forward_rate)
            rates.append(forward_rate + jump/10000)
        dates.append(value_date)
        rates.append(forward_rate)
    return dates, rates

evaldate = ql.Date(21, 11, 2024)
ql.Settings.instance().setEvaluationDate(evaldate)
cdr = ql.TARGET()

test_base_curve_data = [
    (ql.Date(28, 11, 2024), 0.03),
    (ql.Date(21, 12, 2024), 0.026)
]

test_spread_data = [
    (ql.Date(21, 11, 2024), ql.Date(25, 11, 2024), 10),
    (ql.Date(21, 11, 2024), ql.Date(15, 12, 2024), 22)
]

test_jump_data = (ql.Date(29, 11, 2024), ql.Date(2, 12, 2024), 100)

dates, rates = get_forward_curve_adjusted_dates_rates(evaldate, test_base_curve_data, test_jump_data)
test_curve = ql.ForwardCurve(dates, rates, ql.Actual360(), ql.TARGET())
test_curve.enableExtrapolation()

handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(test_curve)
spread_end_dates = [row[1] for row in test_spread_data]
spreads = [ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(row[2]/10000)) for row in test_spread_data]
spread_curve = ql.SpreadedBackwardFlatZeroInterpolatedTermStructure(handle, spreads, spread_end_dates)
spread_curve.enableExtrapolation()

